# Diverting a file write to process

Tags: files, text-processing, io-redirection

I have an OSX GUI application which I can't change - it writes new CVS lines to a log file when it completes a job. I'd like to work with these new lines, but they are constantly being added.

Is there a way to redirect the application's output directly into a script where I can then process the new lines as it generates them? Reading the file every X seconds to pick up changes isn't desirable, and while I could use `launchd` to detect changes to the file and process them that way - I'm looking for something a bit more elegant. Any ideas (with examples - I'm learning) would be much appreciated.

#### EDIT

I'm not sure it's the best approach, but I've managed to get instant results via tail's -F flag. While I'm able to filter for the last line, the first time it runs, when the file is updated, it outputs all the lines not just the last one (as desired).

```
tail -F -n 2 '/path/to/Epson4880_audit.txt' | grep "."
```

Comment: So it looks like there are two different approaches - some sort of file watching utility: launchd, fswatch (some of which are new to me) or a FIFO pipe. Having looked at FIFO im not sure if what Im doing actually requires the overhead and complexity (I might just be skittish here). That said with a file watch system, I have to develop a mechanism to prevent duplicate entries, and race conditions if new lines written are written in rapid succession.

Comment: I have the same problem with this as I did with my own implementation in the post. Basically tail doesn't seem honor the `-n0` as I was expecting - every time the file saves, the entire file is read rather then just the last line.

Comment: @don_crissti at least with a single invocation of tail, there dosen't seem to be a way to just get just the last line when using ` tail -F -n0`. It will deliver the last line, the fist time, but on every file update it outputs the whole file. Happy to be proved wrong. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246146/bash-processing-last-line-in-file-only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace the output file by a FIFO and make your other program get its input from it.

For example:

```
mkfifo Epson4880_audit.txt
# launch your program
grep "." Epson4880_audit.txt
```

Note this is not guaranteed to work. Some program check that their output is a real file. And if you do want to keep a log of the lines, the second process has to make sure to print them as they arrive. For example doing `tee real_Epson4880_audit.txt | grep "."`. Please also note that you won't be able to launch your first program without the second because the first process will be forced to wait for a reader. In the case you want to run the first program without the second, you'll have to remove the FIFO first.

Comment: Right, I had in mind the case of a RDWR FIFO. I correct the answer.

Comment: Im going to mark this the correct answer as you precisely address my question about redirecting file writes. Ultimately I'll probably use @slm's approach and monitor the file with the likes of `fswatch` because it seems simpler, and less work (in some respects) to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Most operating systems have a facility where you can subscribe to the activity on a file. In Linux this facility is built into the kernel and is called iNotify. You could create something along those lines to watch the file for activity and then handle these updates.

Here are some resources to get you started with understanding iNotify:

- [Monitor file system activity with inotify](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html)
- [Kernel Korner - Intro to inotify](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8478)

Even though these pages show C/C++ code you do not have to develop your own tools to interact with it. There are command line tools that you can use to subscribe a file and/or directory and then receive notifications.

**NOTE:** On OSX you'll use something similar called [`kqueue`](http://people.freebsd.org/~jlemon/papers/kqueue.pdf). I found this thread that discusses a lot of the options over on Stack Overflow, titled: [Is there a command like “watch” or “inotifywait” on the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac).

There are tools that offer similar facilities to `inotifywait` on OSX such as [`launchd`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html), [`kqwait`](https://github.com/sschober/kqwait), [`fswatch`](https://github.com/unphased/fswatch) or [`watchdog`](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog).

The other approach that you could take with this is to look at how monitoring tools such as Nagios monitor log files for activity. There is a wealth of plugins to Nagios that do exactly what you're trying to do. Some of them monitor a file just for activity while others monitor the files for specific strings. Take a look at the plugins page.

[Nagios Plugins - Category: Log Files](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Log-Files)

Comment: iNotify is Linux only, the OP mentioned OSX, where I suppose it's kevent/kqueue like on BSDs.

Comment: the 'i' in iNotify threw me, sadly its an OSX environment - thanks for the tip though - it might help someone else.

Comment: @orionrush - see the link I provided on SO. There are other tools such as [fswatch](https://github.com/unphased/fswatch) and [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog).

Comment: some good tool tips there, I'll have to do some research...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the points to up-vote this. Its a solid suggestion and you've sketched out the landscape very well. Thanks for adding in the thread on OSX equivalents.

Comment: @orionrush - no problem. Thanks for the question, good luck on getting your solution implemented. Feel free to post back how you make out. Either as an update to your question or as a comment on my answer would suffice.